# jQuery - Select and change value of input parent div

Tags: jquery

I am now trying to fill in the input box within the LI that contains the word John, I know I need to use .val but not sure how to implement

http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1258/

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div>John Resig</div>
        <input class="myinput"></input>
        <input class="myinput2"></input>
        <input class="myinput3"></input>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div>Simon Resig</div>
        <input class="myinput"></input>
        <input class="myinput2"></input>
        <input class="myinput3"></input>
    </li>
    <li>
    <div>Arthur Resig</div>
        <input class="myinput"></input>
        <input class="myinput2"></input>
        <input class="myinput3"></input>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I think I need a combination of...

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
$("#myinput").val('thisistheclass');
```

Anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.next()` to select the immediate next `sibling` of an element. In your context `input` elements are the immediate sibling to the `divs`

Just try,

```
  $("div:contains('John')")
      .css( "text-decoration", "underline" )
        .next('#myinput')
          .val('hello');
```

Additionally as satpal said in the comment, you should not have *same ids for multiple elements*.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1262/)

Answer (score 1):

**IDs must be unique**

You can use [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/), Assuming you want to set text to input following div

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).next().val('thisistheclass');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/qYdwR/1261/)

Comment: What if I want to select the input within that li with the specific id of myinput?  For example if there were lots of other inputs?

Comment: @fightstarr20, You can use `.siblings('#yourid')`. but remeber ids must be unique in Docs

Comment: @fightstarr20, See http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/qYdwR/1263/ if you have any concern ping me

Comment: I have updated the JSFiddle with another scenario, this time there is more content inside the li - http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1264/ - Now the #yourid input can't be found

Comment: @fightstarr20, [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/qYdwR/1266/)  uses closest() and then find() its better solution

Comment: I have tried to apply it to some real world code but its not working - http://jsfiddle.net/qYdwR/1267/ any ideas?